# Android Identify Valid Google Referral URL

Tags: android, google-play

Below is the valid URL to get referral parameter from Google :

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcd.mypackage&referrer=utm_source%3D0%26utm_id%3D1%26utm_campaign%3D2
```

Below are the cases which don't have referral string but still URL is valid and takes you to Google store (if application is there)

```
1) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcd.mypackage&try
2) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcd.mypackage&
3) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcd.mypackage
```

In such cases how can we handle URL or put some checks to identify only valid referral URL?

Comment: Where are You trying to validate such url? On mobile device or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you asked, but if you meant how to check this in the Android app after installation, you don't have a real problem.

The referral feature works as follow:

1. On android device url is directing to the google play app.
2. The user choose to install the app.
3. The google play app check if the `referrer` variable is exist in the url from step 1. Only if exist it broadcast the `referrer` value to the app.

Since in your links the `referrer` variable is not exist your broadcast receiver won't get anything and you have nothing to check.

Hope it helped